# i want to take my thumbnail of my every user profile page?

Tags: php, image, thumbnails

i m creating a site something like [about.me](http://about.me). and about.me is creating a thumbnail of their user profile. i want the same for my site. and i thing they are not using any apis. i want to save user profile page thumbnail in some folder.

Is any one know how to take thumbnail of web page and save in some folder.

i know about the

[thumbnailzr](http://www.thumbalizr.com/)

[Websnapr](http://www.websnapr.com/)

and other api provided site.

i think if i use this apis then it will take lots of time to create the thumbnail.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a way to automatically take a screenshot of a website through a URL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2109173/is-there-a-way-to-automatically-take-a-screenshot-of-a-website-through-a-url)

Comment: But this all are the api site and i dont want api site.

Comment: What OS is running on your server? If windows then http://www.php.net/imagegrabscreen Otherwise your system may not even have a graphical interface to run the browser.

Comment: @PathikGandhi: Have you even read the first answer? See this question it refers: [How can I take a screenshot of a website with PHP and GD?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/627301/how-can-i-take-a-screenshot-of-a-website-with-php-and-gd).

Comment: i dont know about that. i m working on the client srver. how to know about the server?? and i think imagegrabscreen is only working on IE.

Comment: @Tadeck  the link will help him only if he is using Windows.  `how to know about the server` phpinfo();

Comment: my system is linux. what can i use in linux?

Comment: @Cheery: To follow that line of thought, the link will answer his question if he is using Windows or is able to use it at least for this single task. Which is not that hard, nor complicated if OP wants to achieve the goal from the question.

Comment: @PathikGandhi: It is still a duplicate even though you added a comment mentioning something that wasn't (and still isn't) in the question itself (that you want a Linux-based solution). See this question: **[Taking website screenshot, server-side, on a Linux rented server, free](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342966/taking-website-screenshot-server-side-on-a-linux-rented-server-free)**

Answer (score 1):

You can use this library : http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/ for client side work, or this http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/ - a server and client side script.

Comment: my system is linux. can i use this in linux?

Comment: @PathikGandhi  yes, you can if you are allowed to use `exec` or `system` functions. you need wkhtmltoimage